# Ajax GET duplicates if bad connection or a lot of DB connections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to GET jSon data from my hosting, but sometimes it duplicate or more when the connection is unstable

```
//Interval to run getChat() every 2 seconds
setInterval(function(){getChat();}, 2000);
//Get Messages from Database
function getChat() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myhosting.net/myscript.php"
  }).done( function( data )
  {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
    var html_ = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
      var result = jsonData.results[i];

      var chatmsg = $("<div></div>").text(result.chattext).html();
      html_ += '<span class="color-'+result.color+'"><b>'+result.usrname+'</b></span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> '+chatmsg+'<br>';     
    }

    $('#page-chat').append(html_);
  });

}
```

Also i have a form and when i send the message with another function, i call getChat() again to refresh my #page-chat content div...

The POST to datbase works fine, i dont have duplicates there, it is just a client side problem with my code, i was thinking to set a CheckState=1 var to check if the ajax GET call got Success, if not,  CheckState=0...that way it wont run again same function, what do you think? ps. it happens when the internet is slow or a lot of people is chatting at same time...this is meant to be an Mobile Chat APP

Comment: Can you post the code where you have a form that also calls `getChat()`?

Comment: this is why an async method to retrieve sync real-world events is not the best match-up. use something ordered, like WebSockets to not only avoid rush mis-orders, but to run smoothly and avoid the kind of net polling that even _can_ potentially get backed up. if you can't use EventSource or WebSockets, at least wait until thje prior ajax request is complete before sending another.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of handling duplication of messages would be to create a chronological ID of each message. This way, even if something arrives later (and it can happen due to many things network related) you will still be able to order your messages.

Generate a timestamp for each message as it reaches the server on the post message, or when it leaves the client.